# Concatenar una lista a sí misma indefinidamente en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Conocen algún método para concatenar una lista a sí misma indefinidamente?

Supongamos la lista:

```html
<ul id="contain">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Quiero encontrar la manera de concatenar sus cinco elementos indefinidamente, el propósito es, por ejemplo, realizar un scroll infinito vertical de sus elementos donde el primer elemento aparezca tras el quinto elemento constantemente tras el primer ciclo de scroll.

Comment: Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de lo que buscas? Sin codigo sera dificil ayudarte.

Comment: Consulta excesivamente pobre, no hay ejemplos o código que requiera analisis

Comment: @n7rc si aún estás intentando aprender la plataforma, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] (o lo vuelvas a completar si ya lo hiciste) y que leas [ask] y [answer]. Tanto tu pregunta como la respuesta necesitan mejoras. Aprende cómo funciona el sitio (que no es un foro al uso) y edita tus publicaciones para mejorarlas con los consejos de los enlaces anteriores. Y si tienes dudas, pásate por el [chat] o busca asistencia en el [help]. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema ha quedado resuelto así:

```js
$(document).ready(append_clone());

function append_clone(){
  $("#contain li").each(function(){
    $("#contain li").clone().appendTo("#contain");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="contain">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta, en que se diferencia de la respuesta aceptada? si esta es la respuesta correcta, deberia ser la aceptada, si no genera confusion. Si esta no es la respuesta correcta, entonces no deberia estar.

Answer (score 2):

No conozco ningúno, pero te he realizado uno:

Lo que hace, es crear una función recursiva, en que comienza procesando al elemento que ya existe como elemento inicial, luego creo un clon de este elemento con el método `elemento.cloneNode()`, y a ese clon le asigno la id de su elemento anterior + 1, y lo introduzco dentro del elemento inicial con `appendChild()` , para luego poder procesar ese elemento como el elemento inicial y volver a repetir el ciclo recursivamente. La variable `max`, determina cuantos niveles de encademiento tendrás, en este caso 10.

En este caso el elemento es un `p`, pero te sirve para cualquier elemento, osea de caso general.

```js
function append_recursive(e, max, flag, d = document) {
 if(flag === max) { return; }
 else { 
 var next_elem = create_append_element(e, d);
 append_recursive(next_elem, max, ++flag, d);
 }
}
function create_append_element(e_from, d) {
 var clon = e_from.cloneNode(true);
     clon.id = parseInt(e_from.id) + 1;
     clon.innerHTML = "Mi id es: " + clon.id + "\ny soy hijo del elemento con id: " + e_from.id;
     e_from.appendChild(clon);
 return clon;
}

window.onload = _ => {
 append_recursive(document.getElementById("0"), 10, 0);
};
```

```html
<p id="0">Soy el primer elemento con ID 0, y fui escrito en el HTML</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, muy amable.

Comment: Tratemos de no contestar preguntas que no demuestran que se haya intentado algo por parte de quien pregunta.